# Access file via masked url only .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain which contains some php files, I have setup url masking like this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /ht.php$
RewriteRule .* /folder/location/user.php [L]
```

when the user accesses `ht.php` they see `user.php`

which is what I wanted but I also want to now block direct access to user.php so they can access it through ht.php but not directly

now I have tried blocking direct access to user.php via htaccess but this also blocks access via ht.php

Is there a way I can let the user access the file using the masked url ht.php but block direct access to `user.php` using `htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to write custom code to check whether the file accessed from ht.php. Else display a 404.